# Error OR-PMSA-03 when trying to make in-app purchase

Tags: google-play-games, google-pay

My mother has been playing a game on her tablet (its called Hidden City), in which she sometimes buy in-game elements to help her progress. But since about 2 months, each time she tries to buy something, Google Play reject the payment by sending the error OR-PMSA-03

Does someone know what this error means and what might cause it ?

We already tried to check with the bank, and according to them, there is no problem with the credit cart she is using, so the error might come either from the game (we already tried to uninstall/reinstall it) or the tablet itself

Thanks,
Méta

Comment: Likely [corrupted cache](https://www.techrepublic.com/google-amp/article/resolve-df-pfa-03-error-in-the-google-play-store/)???

Comment: @beeshyams We already tried to uninstall/reinstall the game, shouldn't it have already cleaned the cache?

Comment: Cache of Play Store

Comment: There is still an error, but it is different this time. It's OR-PMSA-35 now